# Index Error Problems

Tags: python-3.x, index-error

So I'm making a calculator that takes in a string and checks to see if it has certain words like add or subtract and then finding integers. However, in my current code, I run it and get this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "python", line 1, in <module>
    File "python", line 7, in calculator
IndexError: string index out of range
```

The code is typed out below.

```
def calculator(string):
    if "add" in string or "Add" in string:
        total = 0
        for i in range(len(string)): #loop for length of string
            try:
                if type(int(string[i])) == int: #checks to see if there is a number in the string
                    try:
                        if type(int(string[i+1])): #checks to see if the number is 2 digits
                            number_1 = int(string[i])*10 
                    except ValueError:
                        number_1 = int(string[i])
                total = total + number_1 #adds all the numbers to a total variable
            except ValueError:
                pass
        print (total)
```

If someone could help me out that would be great! Thanks so much!

Comment: Your indentations are broken.

Comment: How should I go about fixing that? I just tried retyping them all out.

Comment: Write the code as you write it in any editor, then select it and press `CTRL+K`

Comment: That didn't work either :(

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is with `type(int(string[i+1]))`

as you have a `for` loop, `i` can already be pointing to the last index of `string`. When you add `1` to that, you get an `IndexError`

Example:

```
s = 'blabla'
for i in range(len(s)):
    print(s[i])
```

Output:

```
b
l
a
b
l
a
```

Example:

```
s = 'blabla'
for i in range(len(s)):
    print(s[i+1])
```

Output:

```
l
a
b
l
a

File "C:\Users\python\scratch\untitled-1.py", line 3, in <module>
  print(s[i+1])

builtins.IndexError: string index out of range
```

Answer (score 0):

Sat down with my friend(@Kay Ace Elits) and realised a bunch of things were amiss but we pieced this together

```
def calculator(string):
    if "add" in string:

        total = 0
        first_string = "" # before a in add
        second_string = "" # after d in add

        value_list = string.split('add')
        for number in value_list:
            total += int(number)

        print(total)

    elif  "Add" in string:
        total = 0
        first_string = ""
        second_string = ""

        value_list = string.split('Add')
        for number in value_list:
            total += int(number)

        print(total)

### our test your can modify for other factors
### like spellings and different operations
string = "22add43"
calculator(string)
```

Comment: when `i=0` that would result in `string[-1]` which is the last element of the string... not sure if you want that.

Comment: thanks @EdwinvanMierlo for bringing that up it was an oversight on my part  will edit the code after running tests.

Comment: your indentation is off